# Fastest way to create string of the same character in Go

Tags: string, performance, go

I'm wondering what the fastest way would be to create a string of `n` instances of the same character. I could imagine a few approaches, some naive and some less so:

**String concatenation (very naive)**

```
func nchars(b byte, n int) string {
    s := ""
    c := string([]byte{b})
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        s += c
    }
    return s
}
```

**Byte slice**

```
func nchars(b byte, n int) string {
    s := make([]byte, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        s[i] = b
    }
    return string(s)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The byte slice approach is at least the one chosen in [`strings.Repeat`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Repeat): see [its source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/strings/strings.go?s=10317:10356#L414):

```
b := make([]byte, len(s)*count)
bp := 0
for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        bp += copy(b[bp:], s)
}
return string(b)
```

So I would go with your second choice.

Comment: @synful yes, it doesn't do exactly what you want, but its implementation remains a good clue as to which one is considered "fast".

Comment: Yeah, and honestly, the overhead due to them copying strings instead of single characters is probably relatively negligible.

Comment: @synful I don't think so. Copying single characters is a single-instruction operation. Copying strings takes more time. Perhaps they might implement an assembly-version of this in the future.

Comment: Right, but if you take that in the context of the many other instructions that are being executed, it's not too bad. I mean, maybe it's 25% slower, but that's peanuts compared to the difference between O(n) and O(n^2), for example.

Comment: @FUZxxl you *can* use unsafe to remove the string -> []byte overhead, but it's a readonly operation.

Answer (score 4):

```
res1 := strings.Repeat(str1, 4)
```

Comment: Please provide a description why do you think this is a correct solution!